# Insert user defaults string not working

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, parse-platform

I was trying now for several hours to figure out what I am missing: I retrieve string values from user defaults and insert them in channel IDs. This is my code:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application            
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
   [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken]

   NSString *channel5 = [defaults stringForKey:@"text_plain5"]; // THIS WORKS NOT

   [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:channel5 forKey:@"channels"];

   [currentInstallation saveInBackground];



    NSString *message = [defaults stringForKey:@"text_plain"]; // THIS WORKS
    NSString *ownNr = [defaults stringForKey:@"text_plain99"]; // THIS WORKS
    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  message, @"alert",
                  @"so.mp3", @"sound",
                  nil];

    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setChannels:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ownNr, nil]];
    [push setData:data];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
```

What is wrong with the first part?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Define "this works not"? Do you get back `nil`? Do you get the wrong value? Does it crash? Explain the problem.

Comment: correct, sorry, it is throwing an exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' If I replace channel5 with @"text" it works.

Comment: So the error is not coming from the line you flagged with `// this works not` but from the next line, correct? This simply means that `channel5` is `nil`. You need to handle that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On it's own, no there's nothing wrong with what you've done here.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *channel5 = [defaults stringForKey:@"text_plain5"];
```

However, since you haven't shown how you're storing these values, we can only speculate on what's wrong. I'd start by checking that first, you are indeed setting a value for `text_plain5`. Keeping in mind, this key is case sensitive. If that isn't the issue, you'll want to make sure that `NSUserDefaults` are being synchronized between the time you save the value, and the time you read the value.

Comment: the user defaults have values, but this might be the problem. This code was actually working for hours, i.e. until I deleted the app and installed it again with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems: I was calling defaultsToRegister -setObject: with a nil key, which was throwing the exception. 
I fixed it by loading a plist with default values at first launch:

```
NSString* pathToUserDefaultsValues = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                      pathForResource:@"Root~iphone"
                                      ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* userDefaultsValues = [NSDictionary   dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToUserDefaultsValues];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsValues];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Danke Ortwin Gentz!